# Anyone know carousel effect plugin for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, slider, carousel

http://www.ralphandrusso.com
On this website if you click 
AW 15/16 (link in bottom). 
I would like to use similar kind of [carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrDfG.jpg) effect plugin into my wordpress website with social media and form to link with it.

Comment: Have you searched "carousel plugin"?  What have you found and what have you tried?

Comment: i have found few carousel plugins but not this kind of product management system kind of mechanism that linked to social media and more importantly enquiry FORM linked with that product code.

Comment: My point was more that, as written, this question is a poor match for Stack Overflow.  Take a look at the [how to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some help improving it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple slider to me and not necessarily a carousel. You can try Owl Carousel, though. That has similar functionality and it's free.

Comment: we need like post carousel with social media and Enquire form of that relevant product. Its kind of product or content management system with full width carousel with relevant product code that linked with form.